# Wait For Duration Decreasing Parameter

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I want to decreasing the parameter of SKAction.waitForDuration(X).

I'm using the Flappy Bird Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUvEiNxWfc - see on minute 7) and I want to do something like

```
var timeToWait:Int = 8

let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
                () in

                self.createWalls()
                timeToWait--
            })

            let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(timeToWait)
            let SpawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
            let spawnDelayForever =   SKAction.repeatActionForever(SpawnDelay)
         self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)
```

However, the parameter for waitForDuration is NSTimer and not a float. What could I do to change that parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

waitForDuration expects a value of type NSTimeInterval.

You can Type cast timeToWait when you pass it to the function:

```
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(timeToWait))
```

By the way, your code seems to want to decrease the delay between each spawn but it will not do that because timeDelay is captured in your creation of the delay action and will not change that action's duration if you modify the variable afterward.

[EDIT]

Here's an example accelerates spawning interval (from 8 to 1) in cycles:

```
  let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({ self.createWalls() })

  var spawnCycle:[SKAction] = []
  for timeToWait in (1...8).reverse()
  {
     spawnCycle.append(spawn)
     spawnCycle.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(timeToWait)))
  }    

  self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(spawnCycle)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to doing that?

Comment: There is, and I could provide an example if you can specify what to do when timeToWait hits zero or becomes negative.  I can manage zero but my time machine won't let me deal with -1, -2 etc.

Comment: Of course, when timeToWait hits zero, we reset it to be equals 8. Thx.

Comment: Thank you, @Alain T. Do you know if there's a way to set a value, like for example, to set timeToWait to be 10 and in another moment to be 5?

Comment: You could run the action with an identifier and remove/recreate it when your game needs to change the frequency